# How to show place with Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am working with the Google Takeout.
They give me data with json file.

```
{
  "timelineObjects" : [ {
    "placeVisit" : {
      "location" : {
        "latitudeE7" : 129255490,
        "longitudeE7" : 776649940,
        "placeId" : "ChIJ_ZQgWXcTrjsR7t4Sqb3Pmi8",
        "address" : "#101, 10th Block, Suncity Corporate Leisure\nSarjapura Outer Ring Road\nIblur Village, Bellandur\nBengaluru, Karnataka 560102\nIndia",
        "name" : "Cheese Care",
        "locationConfidence" : 99.093636
      },
      "duration" : {
        "startTimestampMs" : "1358972055436",
        "endTimestampMs" : "1360407467023"
      },
      "centerLatE7" : 129255325,
      "centerLngE7" : 776650031,
      "visitConfidence" : 64,



      "otherCandidateLocations" : [ {
        "latitudeE7" : 129253900,
        "longitudeE7" : 776647590,
        "placeId" : "ChIJjwwbqoITrjsR95ZXtjEF2tU",
        "name" : "Zenith",
        "locationConfidence" : 0.5477843
      }],


      "editConfirmationStatus" : "NOT_CONFIRMED"
    }
  } ]
}
```

I didn't get any idea how to show places with these `latitudeE7` and `longitudeE7`. They are very big value!!!

Comment: [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zc4y1qjh/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply each `Latitude` and `Longitude` with

**`0.0000001`**